# Set field as non-mandatory on save

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

How can I programmatically set fields as non-mandatory before the record is saved? I tried to do it via *isMandatory* method placed in a save record function on a script that's attached to the form. It works fine if the user is pressing 'save' button. But my scenario is more complicated.

I have a bundled UE script that saves a custom record related to a vendor, that also makes a change on the vendor record. It uses the 'save' method to do so.

The script saves the record by using the default vendor form. Unfortunately, we use a few different subsidiaries, and the default form has some mandatory fields set which aren't set on other vendor forms. So when the mentioned script saves records for one of the subsidiaries it breaks by displaying the prompt with *'Please enter value(s) for: '* and a list of mandatory fields. So it seems that the script attached to the form isn't triggered at all.

I'm not allowed to amend the default form, and I'm not allowed to change the bundled script, so I can't apply '*ignoreMandatoryFields*' method.

Anybody knows how to handle this correctly?

Comment: Why don't you set the form while updating the vendor with your script?

Comment: Unsure what you mean. I can't change the form within the script because the script attached to the form isn't even triggered. Before it has a chance it's stopped by the message 'please entrer value(s).